# Talmud Jerusalem Kiddushin 3,8

Tags: talmud-yerushalmi

What does this passage from the Jerusalem [Talmud Kiddushin 3,8](https://www.sefaria.org/Jerusalem_Talmud_Kiddushin.3.8) mean? Does this refer to a father who married his minor daughter and then filed for divorce because she is unsuitable for the priesthood? The text is not clear.

Comment: If I understand your question, you sound like you are thinking the father actually marries his child. That is not what this is saying. It is dealing with motive of a parent for allowing their daughter to enter into a marriage with someone else.

Comment: Can you quote the specific passage here?

Comment: Yes Yaacov, I know. Intends to another man.

Comment: The whole passage, what does it want to teach?

Comment: “I preliminarily married off my daughter, married her preliminarily and received her bill of divorce while she was underage,” why was he divorced? The reason?

Comment: The point of the Mishnah is to discuss if the father is believed without any proof. If the daughter is still under 12, then since she is still in his control, he is believed. However if she is over 12, even if he’s discussing a story that took place prior to her being 12, he’s no longer believed as she is currently not in his control.

Comment: Is your question just about the mishna or about the whole page? If just the mishnah, clarify that your question is about that mishna.

Comment: Yes this mishnah.

Comment: The text is clear; you just don't have the background to understand it, unfortunately.

Comment: "Received her bill of divorce" means he received the bill on his daughter's behalf from her husband. The father and the husband are different people. Also worth noting that even though under some circumstances a father's betrothal of his daughter (to a 3rd party, I reiterate) and acceptance of a bill of divorce on behalf of his daughter were legally binding, that doesn't imply the betrothal is permitted in the first place (SA EH 37:8, Ishus 3:19, 10:16). Nor does it imply marital relations would've occurred when she was a minor (Nidda 13b). Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/65741