Can someone refute these claims against Judaism?

EVIDENCE THAT TRADITIONAL JEWISH LAW ALLOWS SEX WITH 3-YEAR-OLDS
Traditional Jewish texts affirm that it is permissible for a Jewish
man to have sex with 3 year old girls. Why?
It is because they are following what they believe to be the example
of their Prophet Isaac.
It is held that Isaac married his wife Rebecca (Rivka) when she was 3
years old.
This belief is based on the text of the Hebrew Bible, as well as
interpretations of the Bible by the highest Jewish authorities in
exegesis like Rashi.
Rashi states:
"FORTY YEARS OLD — For when Abraham came from Mount Moriah he received
the news that Rebecca was born (22:20). Isaac was then thirty-seven
years old, because at that time Sarah died and from the birth of Isaac
until the Binding — when Sarah died — there were 37 years since she
was 90 years old when Isaac was born and 127 when she died, as it is
said, (23:1) “And the life of Sarah was [one hundred and twenty seven
years]” — thus Isaac was then 37 years old. At that period Rebecca was
born and he waited until she was fit for marriage — 3 years — and then
married her (Seder Olam)."
Look at the link and check for yourself.
https://sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.25.20.1?lang=bi
Jewish law holds that since Isaac had sex with a 3 year old, this
provides a norm of permissibility for all later Jews to follow.
The Talmud endorses such a view. Hence, it teaches that older Jewish
men are permitted to have sex with 3 year olds. This is reflected in
many passages.
One is Nidda 44b
"MISHNA: A girl who is three years and one day old, whose father
arranged her betrothal, is betrothed through intercourse, as the
halakhic status of intercourse with her is that of intercourse in all
halakhic senses."
https://sefaria.org/Niddah.44b.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en
This same idea is reiterated in Sanhedrin 55b, which states:
"Rav Yosef says: Come and hear a resolution from a mishna (Nidda 44b):
A girl who is three years and one day old whose father arranged her
betrothal is betrothed with intercourse, as the legal status of
intercourse with her is that of full-fledged intercourse. And in a
case where the childless husband of a girl who is three years and one
day old dies, if his brother, the yavam, engages in intercourse with
her, he acquires her as his wife; and if she is married, a man other
than her husband is liable for engaging in intercourse with her due to
the prohibition of intercourse with a married woman."
https://sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.55b.4?lang=bi
Today, many Jewish apologists claim that the Talmud does not really
say what it appears to say.
However, the same teaching is explicitly affirmed in Josef Karo's
Shulchan Aruch - one of the two most authoritative texts on Jewish law
and the interpretation of legal material in the Talmud.
The relevant passage in Shulchan Aruch reads as follows:
"All the Laws Concerning Betrothal of a Minor
"The father may betroth his daughter without her consent, all the time
she is a minor. Likewise when she is a na’arah the father has control
over her and the betrothal money belongs to him.
"Likewise he is entitled to her finds, to the production of her hands,
and to her wedding contract. If she be widowed or divorced from the
betrothal, he is entitled to everything until she comes of age.
Therefore the father accepts the betrothal money, etc. of his daughter
from the day she is born until she comes of age. Even if she was a
deaf-mute or insane and the father betrothed her, behold she is a
fully married woman.
If she were three years old and one day she may be betrothed by means of Bi’ah [i.e., sexual intercourse] with the consent of her
father. If she is younger than this, if her father hands her over for
intercourse, she is not betrothed.
Look at the link and check for yourself.

Are these arguments valid? Or are they a misrepresentation of the religion?

Effectiveness and permissibility are two different things.  If someone shoots someone else, that person is dead.  Doesn't mean the killer was allowed to do it.

The "claims against Judaism" are copied from this "tweet" on X https://x.com/Haqiqatjou/status/1740404893683224719

This is my go to link to debunking this antisemitic claptrap: https://talmud.faithweb.com/. Doesn't work on mobile

related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65726/does-the-talmud-promote-pedophilia


It is held that Isaac married his wife Rebecca (Rivka) when she was 3 years old.

Even if that is correct she wasn't a three year old the way we think of three year olds today. She was capable of going to a well to get water for her family and then giving water to ten camels so she must have had the physical and mental maturity of a modern teenager.   Secondly even assuming she was biologically  three years old at the time (there are other opinions in the medrash) that does not mean the marriage was consummated at the time.

MISHNA: A girl who is three years and one day old, whose father arranged her betrothal, is betrothed through intercourse,

There is a legal technicality. See below

If she were three years old and one day she may be betrothed by means of Bi’ah [i.e., sexual intercourse] with the consent of her father

Again this is a legal technicality. It is entirely  conceivable that is specific (but of course  very limited) circumstances it would benefit a girl that her father as her legal guardian marry her off with this being the only way to do so. On a general level however that is not allowed.
Whoever  misinformed you about this    gave you the location of the Mishna but did not give you the source  of where this is written in  Shulchan Aruch. For a simple reason. He did not want you to read a few lines further because you would see that it clearly says  (SA OH 37:8) you
מצוה שלא יקדש בתו כשהיא קטנה עד שתגדיל ותאמר בפלוני אני
רוצה It is a mitzvah that one should not betroth his daughter while she is a minor, rather until she has grown and says “I want(to marry) so and so" (The Gemara this is based on says it is forbidden) The Rema continues to discuss doing so and says it is done today (then) because of the   benefit the girl and risk to her if you wait until she is older. The Rambam Ishus 3:19 also  says similar to the Shulchan Aruch based on the same Gemara.
This is discussing child marriage in general. Marriage   through intercourse is forbidden behavior  even for an adult. The Rambam Ishus 3:21 says
אֵין מְקַדְּשִׁין בְּבִיאָה לְכַתְּחִלָּה וְאִם קִדֵּשׁ בְּבִיאָה מַכִּין אוֹתוֹ מַכַּת מַרְדּוּת
If a man marries through intercourse , he is given lashes This is based on explicit Gemaras
